# ProgressBar problems while program downloading file

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, download, progress-bar

I have a problem with a simple updater program. It should to download archive and extract it. Well, this works fine. But i cannot overcome progressbar.
It shows at setProgressBar(progressBar1.Maximum/20) fine.
But all other changes of it's value doesn't shows at all. I can't define reason for this behavior. Could anyone help me?

UPD: It seems that e.ProgressPercentage returns always 0, and only once 100, right before download is complete.

Here is my code:

```
static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

void UpdaterForm_Shown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    setProgressBar(progressBar1.Maximum/20);

    UpdateProgram(address, login, password);

    setProgressBar(progressBar1.Maximum);

    ExecuteProgram(Path + "../" + programName + ".exe");

    Application.Exit();     
}

private void UpdateProgram(string pathToUpdateArchive, string login, string pass)
{
    string downloadedArchive = null;

    Thread downloadAsync = new Thread(() => DownloadFileFromFtp(pathToUpdateArchive, login, pass, out downloadedArchive));
    downloadAsync.Name = "downloadAsync";
    downloadAsync.Start();

    _waitHandle.WaitOne();

    ExtractFile(downloadedArchive, Path + "/../");
}

private void DownloadFileFromFtp(string address, string login, string password, out string archivePath)
{
    fileName = address.Substring(address.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    try
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);

        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);     

        archivePath =Path + fileName;
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(address), archivePath);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}

void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    setProgressBar(e.ProgressPercentage*7/10 + 10);
}

void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _waitHandle.Set();
}

private void setProgressBar(int value)
{
    if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { progressBar1.Value = value; });
    else
        progressBar1.Value = value;
}
```

Comment: BackGroundWorker has a show progress that work great.

Comment: Have you tried calling Refresh()?

Comment: UNeverNo, tried. Nothing changes. Maybe something wrong with calling from _Shown method? But msdn says, that all elements at this time must be fully initialized.

Comment: Where is your progressBar1.Maximum initialized? What is it initialized to?

Comment: Ray Eatmon, Minimum = 0, Maximum = 100

Comment: Is `wc_DownloadProgressChanged` even getting called? And what's up with the math here: `e.ProgressPercentage*7/10 + 10`

Comment: Matt Burland, Yes, `wc_DownloadProgressChanged` is called.
Talking about math... It just transorms values from 0..100 to 10..80.